# Twilio video tracks differentiation

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

In my application i have a user that is simultaneously using two video tracks (screen sharing and a webcam). Firs when the user connects The webcam starts and then the screen sharing track gets added.

In the muddle of this session i need an ability to enable the user camera switching. I used this guide here to implement this feature: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/06/switching-cameras-twilio-video-chat.html

However when i do something like this:

```
const tracks = Array.from(localParticipant.videoTracks.values());
localParticipant.unpublishTracks(tracks);
localParticipant.publishTrack(localVideoTrack);
```

I unpublish both video tracks(screen sharing and camera) and only adding a camera track. Is there a way to add a property to the track(other than "kind") that will allow me to make this distinction?
Because right now the only way i can do it is tracking if the user has screen sharing enabled and re-connect both tracks in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

All `Track`s within Twilio Video have a `name` property which is the track ID by default. However, you can set the `name` of the track when you [create](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.19.2/docs/LocalVideoTrack.html#LocalVideoTrack__anchor) or [publish it](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.19.2/docs/LocalParticipant.html#publishTrack__anchor).

For example:

```js
localParticipant.publishTrack(localVideoTrack, { name: "camera" }
```

You can then read the name from the `LocalTrack` or `RemoteTrack` object later.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: After doing `localParticipant.publishTrack(localVideoTrack, { name: 'camera' })` name still remains randomly generated number, both video and audio tracks do this

Comment: The only thing working is `createLocalVideoTrack({ deviceId: myID, name: 'camera' })`

Comment: However naming video inputs with the same name created an issue for me when user switches camera and does `unpublishTrack() - publishTrack()` one after another this created an `Track name is duplicated`error. and since unpublishTrack() does not return a primice there is no way to wait for it

Comment: Perhaps you can start the name with "camera" but then use the device's name as a suffix (you can get the names of the devices with `mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`)?

Comment: what i ended up adding a random string because if i use the device id in my app the user could still generate this error (selecting the same camera from dropdown will trigger an this action)